# ker(T) of linear unbounded functional $T: X\to R$ is dense subset of X

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a normed space, $T: X\to R$ a linear unbounded functional. I have to show that

a) ker(T) is dense in X

b) $ker(T) \subset X $

---

I tried to show this with contraposition:

Assume $ker(T)$ is not dense in X.

$\exists x_0\in X$ and there exists an open ball $U(x_0)$ which is disjunct to $Ker(T)$.

$T(U-x_0)$ is convex(linear image of convex set) and symmetric ($a\in T(U-x_0) \implies -a\in T(U-x_0)$.

---

my final goal is to show that f has to be bounded then... but I don't find a way to continue

Comment: i have seen that, but i would like to make my proof-idea via contraposition work.

i thing next step would be showing that $T(U-x_0)$ is bounded